# gitlab - icons replaced by rectangles

Tags: gitlab

I recently installed gitlab and it seems that all of the icons are replaced by rectangles. Everything else seems to be working correctly.

[image: gitlab-boxes]

Any idea what could be causing this?

edit: on another computer I seem to get Korean characters instead of the boxes. So obviously the boxes were the lack of that character set.
[image: gitlab-characters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually resolved with:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

If you have a custom root in your GitLab url (that is, if GitLab is accessible through `http://myserver/aroot/...` instead of just `http://myserver/`), then some url rewriting can help (as [proposed in this issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3182#issuecomment-14666121))

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/gitlab/(.*) http://xxx.xxx.xx/$2
```

For Apache configure, the [issue 50](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/pull/50) has the latest up-to-date content.

Comment: Hi @VonC, I have a custom Gitlab URL and I'm using nginx. Where do I need to put those rules to get it working?

Comment: @VictorHugo those are Apache rewrite rules, so they would need to be adapted in the `nginx.conf` file (mentioned in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/nginx)

Comment: @VonC Thank you for your answer. But, I think I will not use relative URL anymore, since the authors of Gitlab are not supporting it. I will change to a subdomain, instead.

Comment: @VictorHugo I agree. I don't have this option. Subdomain is a must.

Comment: @VonC Just for curiosity, are you the developer of Gitlab?

Comment: @VictorHugo no, I am not. Just a user.